# How to break these two words in two line

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have design this box with angular material. I can not break these two words in two line(up and down).i have included a image. Here i want 1349 and New Feedback in two line. I am new in angular material. thanks

```
 <style>
    .box-item {
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
        width: 100px;
        height: 120px;
    }
    .box-text {
        color:white;
    }
</style> 

   <div layout="row" style="padding: 32px;" ng-cloak>

<md-whiteframe class="md-whiteframe-2dp box-item" md-colors="[enter image description here][1]background:'blue-400'}"
               flex-sm="45" flex-gt-sm="35" flex-gt-md="25" layout
               layout-align="end center" layout-margin>
    <span class="md-display-1 box-text">1349</span>
    <span class="box-text">New Feedbacks</span>
</md-whiteframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a **css** question.

You want to order 2 inline elements (span) in 2 lines.
You should try to style one of them as block element *or* to add `br` tag between them.

```
 <style>
  .box-item {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: cornflowerblue;
      height: 120px;
  }
  .box-text {
      color:white;
      display: block;
  }
</style>
```

Example [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/u8hstt4g/1)

Comment: thanks. But it does not work in my angular material project

Comment: I updated the CSS try it, if it wrong tell me how it appear in your project

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `<span>` tag is an `inline` element by default and only takes up as much width as necessary.

If you need to use a span and require the item's on separate lines then either change the behaviour of the element through `CSS` by changing it's display property to `block` as stated by Cuzi, add a single line break between the elements using the `<br>` tag or use a block-level element such as the `<div>` tag.

I recommend using the right element for the job. So a block-level tag like the `<div>` tag would be ideal. This would cause both elements to take up the full width available and thus be on separate lines without the requirement for an extra line of css, (plus you save a byte of space per element within the HTML!

Heres how to do it in CSS.

```
.box-text {
    color:white;
    display: block;
}
```

Heres with a `<br>` tag:

```
<span class="md-display-1 box-text">1349</span>
<br>
<span class="box-text">New Feedbacks</span>
```

**And the simplest and most semantic of the three**, with div tags:

```
<div class="md-display-1 box-text">1349</div>
<div class="box-text">New Feedbacks</div>
```